# Are the "procps" utilities available in a weird name/path on common AIX?

Tags: linux, aix, watch

I have to deal with a very poorly loaded out AIX system for a development project. One thing I find missing are utilities common to Linux systems, such as those in the [procps collection](http://procps.sf.net). Is there a convention on AIX for names or paths under which utilities common from the Linux world would be installed?

---

For instance, the `watch` in `/usr/sbin/` on AIX is not the `watch` found on Linux systems. The Linux version runs a command periodically and keeps its most recent output on screen. The AIX version is a privileged auditing/logging tool. I want to know if there's someplace I should look for the Linux version, or if I'd need to build it for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various GNU utilities are available for AIX, but they're generally not installed

Have a look in /opt/freeware to see what exists, and if there's not much there then start with the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/index.html), but you'll find that you end up having to build a few of the more common ones yourself (but GCC, GNU make, etc are included to let you do that).

Answer (score 0):

Most of those utilities will be found on any Unix variant, even if they don't use the `/proc` filesystem (although AIX does). Have you tried to find the ones you're looking for with one of the following?

- type -a
- which
- whereis
- whence
- locate
- find

Which utilities in particular are you missing?

**Edit**: Your tags include "`watch`" which should be in `/usr/sbin` on AIX.